# How to trigger mouseover event only one when there are two child element inside the element

Tags: jquery, mouseover

Recently I have an element like this:

```
<p>Some text
<a href='#'>
    <img src="">
    Some text 1
</a></p>
```

When I add a mouseover event on `a` and I hover around `Some text 1`, it will trigger mouseover event once. However, when I move my mouse from `Some text 1` to the image, there will be another mouseover event triggered. How can I ensure the mouseover event is triggered only once? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show your jquery code?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is what is called an 'Event Bubble'. You need to only apply the mouseover event on the a tag. If you apply if on the p tag, it will be trigger when you mouseover any child and the p tag itself. All child elements send events up the stack.

```
<!-- 
   This will cause the duplicated fired events when mouse over any element
   inside the p tag and over the child elements
-->
<p id="hoverOverMe">Some text
  <a href='#'>
    <img src="">
    Some text 1
  </a>
</p>
```

Working example

```
<p >Some text
  <a id="hoverOverMe" href='#'>
    <img src="">
    Some text 1
  </a>
</p>

<script>
  document.querySelector('#hoverOverMe')
    .addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
      console.log(event);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. I found that using mouseenter instead will not have this kind of issue.